# How to calculate Local Binary Pattern Histograms with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I have already seen that OpenCV provides a classifier based on LBP [histograms](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#local-binary-patterns-histograms):

But I want to have access to the LBP histogram itself. For instance:

```
histogram = calculate_LBP_Histogram( image )
```

Is there any function that performs this in OpenCV?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can get the C++ code for computing LBP using OpenCV's Mat data structure here:

http://www.bytefish.de/blog/local_binary_patterns

You should be able to find the Python version as well on the same site.

The code is written by Philipp Wagner, who I believe contributed the face recognition code you mentioned to OpenCV, so it should be the same thing.

The LBP code is found in the file: OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp as a static function. Unfortunately, it does not appear to be exposed for public use (at least for OpenCV 2.4.2).

Comment: Thanks, Do you know what additional changes need to be done (besides removing the `static` from the LBP functions, and building the project) to expose this in the Python version of OpenCV?

Comment: Hi @eran. If you wish to have LBP available using Python, consider the scikit-image library: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_binary_pattern.html But otherwise to make the LBP available for Python you need to do additional work to write the Python bindings for that function.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426765/exposing-the-lbp-descriptors-from-opencv-in-python/18431418#18431418