# Exposing the LBP descriptors from OpenCV in Python

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I want to be able to calculate the LBP discriptor in python using OpenCV.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733448/how-to-calculate-local-binary-pattern-histograms-with-opencv) I need to compile openCV again.

I changed the `elbp()` functions in `opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp`, so they won't be statisc anymore.
Now I have to declare them in an HFile (let's say i created `elbp.hpp`, or should I add this to an existing file?):

```
// This is a header file created to expose the elbp (evaluate LBP) functions

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

namespace cv {

Mat elbp(InputArray src, int radius, int neighbors);
Mat elbp(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int radius, int neighbors);
Mat spatial_histogram(InputArray _src, int numPatterns, int grid_x, int grid_y, bool /*normed*/);
};
```

In order to compile OpenCV I followed instructions [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20:%20Debian), and created the cv2.so shared object.

**My question is, how to create python "wrappers" (if I'm using the right word) to be able to call the elbp() functions from python? I feel I am missing a crucial step here.**

For example, the cv2.HogDescriptor() function exists in python, I want to similarly expose the LBP descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually the same problem, if not the same question, as [how to call a dll in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-from-python) - But you *can* use either [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes) or [swig](http://www.swig.org/) however since there is already a python interface into OpenCV your best bet is to take a look to see how the existing one is done.

It may also be worth taking a look at [pyopencv](https://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/) which provides a [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) based interface.

### Update:

To see how the current system does things take a look at `CMakeLists.txt` in `opencv/modules/python` and you will find that a number of generated headers are created by `opencv/modules/python/src2/gen2.py` - you will need to spend some time looking at these two files.

Comment: Thanks Steve. My question is how to use the existing interface. I do not understand how it works and how it links to python.

Comment: It worked, I answered the question to help all future searches for this :) Thanks alot steve!

Answer (score 8):

So, it worked.

To make the function accessible: .

1. I made the following change to facerec.cpp, from:

   ```
   static void elbp(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int radius, int neighbors)
   {
   ...
   }    

   static Mat elbp(InputArray src, int radius, int neighbors) {
       Mat dst;
       elbp(src, dst, radius, neighbors);
       return dst;
   }

   static Mat spatial_histogram(InputArray _src, int numPatterns,
                            int grid_x, int grid_y, bool /*normed*/)
   {
   ...
   }
   ```

   to:

   ```
   void elbp(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int radius, int neighbors)
   {
   ...
   }    

   Mat elbp(InputArray src, int radius, int neighbors) {
       Mat dst;
       elbp(src, dst, radius, neighbors);
       return dst;
   }

   Mat spatial_histogram(InputArray _src, int numPatterns,
                            int grid_x, int grid_y, bool /*normed*/)
   {
   ...
   }
   ```
2. I added the following into `/modules/contrib/include/opencv2/include/contrib.hpp` under the `cv` namespace:

   ```
   CV_EXPORTS_W void elbp(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int radius, int neighbors);
   ```
3. I then creted a `release` folder in the opencv root.
4. From within that folder, I ran:

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
   ```
5. Next, I ran `make`
6. take the cv2.so shared object created under `/lib` and put it where python looks for the packages. For me, it was `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
7. run python

   ```
   from cv2 import spatial_histogram
   ```

Voila!