# Histogram calculation for variance local binary pattern (VLBP) in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv3.0, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I want to calculate the histogram for **Variance local binary pattern** of a gray scale image using OpenCV C++.

Can someone explain me how to exactly find histogram for variance LBP in OpenCV C++ and what exactly it means?

Also please provide some links that are useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAR is a rotation invariant measure of local variance (have a look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2002.1017623) for a more in-depth explanation) defined as:

[image: VAR]

where *P* is the number of pixels in the local neighbourhood and *μ* is the average intensity computed across the local neighbourhood.

LBP variance (LBPV) is a texture descriptor that uses VAR as an adaptive weight to adjust the contribution of the LBP code in histogram calculation (see [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2009.08.017) for details). The value of the *k*<sup>th</sup> bin of the LBPV histogram can be expressed as:

[image: LBPV]

where *N* and *M* are the number of rows and columns of the image, respectively, and *w* is given by:

[image: w]

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733448/how-to-calculate-local-binary-pattern-histograms-with-opencv/13738785#13738785) the code for calculating LBP using OpenCV is not available for public use, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426765/exposing-the-lbp-descriptors-from-opencv-in-python/18431418#18431418) you can find a workaround to make that function accesible.