# Extracting LBPFeatures in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to extract the LBPFeatures of an image using OpenCV and C++, but there seems to be no in-built function to extract the features.

Can anyone help me?
I need to find the feature points and not the histogram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate Local Binary Pattern Histograms with OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733448/how-to-calculate-local-binary-pattern-histograms-with-opencv)

Comment: Calculating the Histogram and extracting the features points are two different things.!

Answer (score 0):

The LBP authors give an optimized C code in one of their papers: [here is the link](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/mvg/files/pdf/pdf_452.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

you can find an old implementation of OpenCV in https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/tree/master/lbp

That libraries are included in newer versions of OpenCV, but the link have an example implementation